# Run-time error with http setRequestHeader

Tags: rest, web-services, vb6

```
Public Function WebRequest(url As String, sVal1 As String, sVal2 As Integer) As String
    Dim xmlhttp As MSXML2.xmlhttp
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml"
    'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Value1", sVal1
    'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Value2", sVal2

    xmlhttp.open "GET", url, False
    xmlhttp.send

    WebRequest = xmlhttp.responseText
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
End Function
```

When I run this function, even with the other paramaters commented out, it fails at the line: `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"` no matter what I put into the request header fields.

I get the error: `Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)' Unspecified error` if I comment out the setRequestHeader line then it works fine, but the API returns that I am missing header fields (expected) I have ried MS XML v3.0 and v6.0 and am completely out of ideas...

Comment: Try doing it after opening the request.

Comment: This was it, thanks! Feel free to post an answer so I can select it as best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your request headers *after* opening the request.

Comment: that was a life-saver. had been struggling for hours, because I thought my encode function was causing the issue!